# How can I handle this error in CodeBLocks?

Tags: macos, codeblocks

I have recently (10 minutes ago) installed CodeBlocks, i have mac as my operating system and when i run the basic "Hello World" program i get this error: (btw i am a beginner in mac os)

```
Last login: Thu Nov 15 16:21:24 on ttys000
MacBooks-MacBook-Pro:~ macbook$ /Users/macbook/Desktop/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/macbook/CodeBlocksProject/Backtracking Test/bin/Debug/Backtracking Test 
sh: /Users/macbook/CodeBlocksProject/Backtracking: No such file or directory

Process returned 127 (0x7F)   execution time : 0.008 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

Comment: Apparently CodeBlocks is stupid and can't cope with spaces in project names.

Comment: Ty, I solved that. I didn't expect something like this...

Comment: Quoting might help. You might however like to join my church, first commandment: Though shalt not trust any funny characters, even if thy OS claims supporting them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the program without a spacebar.
I found this out recently...

Comment: What does "without a spacebar" mean? Do you mean "without a space in the filename"?

Comment: Like the filename when you create a new project with the name "Hello World" delete the space between so that it's called "HelloWorld".

Comment: Idk why mac os doesn't like spaces in the name. On windows it isn't a problem.